# Build Visual Studio Solution without Compile

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, fasm

Can Visual Studio build Solutions without a Compile step? I have a Pre-Build event that builds a .obj library and I just want the Visual Studio .sln to link against it. If I put a dummy Main.cpp file in the Solution, it will Compile that, then link against my Prebuild Event output. Without this dummy file though, the Linking never occurs.

I could put a Post-Build event Link in there, but the default Linking step has a lot of (Macro?) values that expand to directories that I would not want to try and mimic. I just want this VS Solution so it's easier as a link-only build script. The Pre-build event assembles some fasmg assembly sources.

Much appreciated..!

*(This may be a duplicate question, but I could not find the duplicate. Will remove if so.)*

Comment: Visual Studio solutions and projects are meant for source coding and editing. If your goal is not to include any source file, you can simply write a generic MSBuild script, without bothering yourself with a project.

Comment: You may be right. I have a temporary workaround but will revisit MSBuild scripting. I tried this and can't remember why I abandoned it, maybe since I'm maintaining multiple build versions, VS2010 onwards, and am dealing with computers that can't modify their PATH, so accessing msbuild, i.e. from .BAT files in a generic manner, is tough. My workaround is to have two Projects, the original with the library, the latter with GoogleTest tests. Due to the latter, the Solution builds. Will update this post when I can revisit MSBuild scripts.

Comment: "so accessing msbuild, i.e. from .BAT files in a generic manner, is tough"? How can that be tough when MSBuild paths can be discovered from registry? No matter how generic you want it to be, a simple search on Stack Overflow can show you examples.

Comment: Pretty sure I already answered that: "dealing with computers that can't modify their PATH": these computers are pretty locked down from a security standpoint. Installing Visual Studio itself requires ticket requests and must be installed by separate teams. If I were to simply double click a .bat file with msbuild in it, I can get "'msbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command..." Sorry I may have had more problems than that, but asked this at the end of August and can't remember. In Visual Studio itself, I do have a workaround and will revisit alternatives when possible.